# Найдите и выведите сумму всех элементов массива используя цикл for

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Изучение цикла for. Цикл for самый сложный цикл в PHP. Он ведет себя так же как его аналог в языке C.

Как найти сумму всех элементов массива используя цикл for?

```
    <?php
$sum = 0;

$arr = [4, 5, 10, 24, 56];

echo  'Сумма массива = '. array_sum($arr);
?>
```

Comment: А зачем это делать таким извращенным способом? :)

Comment: Изучаю цикл for. Если знаете ответ помогайте. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: @Григорий тогда Вам лучше открыть статейку в интернете и почитать о нем, заодно написав пару своих простейших примеров по прочтенному. Просто данный в лоб ответ не поможет в изучении.

Comment: Все есть тут http://php.net/manual/ru/intro-whatis.php

Comment: Я с вами полностью согласен, но если бы справка на сайте php.net полностью решала все вопросы, то все бы ли бы программистами. Я очень благодарен форуму, он помогает мне сдвинутся с мертвой точки.

Comment: И вообще зачем форум? Бери да читай справку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php 
  $sum = 0;
  $arr = array(4, 5, 10, 24, 56);

  for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) { 
    $sum += $arr[$i];
  }

  echo $sum;
?>
```

Почитайте: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.for.php